# Elasticsearch filter aggregations

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregation

We have a lots of data where there is a boolean which determine is the data is actvie (display it) or not. These are for example skills like PHP and Java. The problem is the query list of users who have skills which are not active, because of it the Elasticsearch aggregations will appear these skills. Somehow can I say it for aggregations I don't want to display it? My current code which is not working:

```
"aggs":{  
        "base":{  
            "filter":{ 
                "term":{  
                    "active":"yes"
                }
            },
            "aggs":{  
                "skills":{  
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"skill",
                        "size":10000,
                        "order":{  
                            "_term":"asc"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

I tried to take the filter outside the aggs, but in this case the ES not shown the users who have non-active skill.

Comment: I did not understand the question completely, could you provide an example?

Comment: You need to put the filter in the aggregations. This page has an example https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html